# SELECT command denied on DELETE

Tags: mysql

I am writing a newsletter service in PHP, in which a user can unsubscribe by clicking a link in the email. This link contains the id of the email, which is then used to find the email in the database, so it can be deleted. The relevant code looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM Emails WHERE id='{$email_id}'
```

Because of security concerns, I thought I create multiple database users, each with just one privilege. I have a select-user, which can only select. And a delete-user, which can only delete. To my confusion, running the code above, while using the username and password of my delete-user, produces the following output:

> SELECT command denied to user 'username'@'host' for column 'id' in table 'Emails'

The issue was easily fixed by granting the delete-user the select-privilege, but I am still confused why this would be necessary.

Why would a user which only deletes rows require the select-privilege?

Comment: Are you aware of SQL Injection?

Comment: Look into prepared statements

Comment: Uh - how can the DB engine "delete" a row without being able to "read" the row - and, importantly, the row's "id" column - first?

Comment: @Ed Heal Yes, I am. $email_id is sanitized.

Comment: Better prepared statements than sanitized - just in case you made a mistake

Comment: @EdHeal if you are curious, you can check out the full code here https://github.com/Rismosch/risWebsite/blob/main/website/newsletter_delete.php I am open for feedback :)

Comment: We all make mistakes once in a while. Or we make sanitisation too good and infuriate the end user. Better prepared statements.

Comment: BTW my email address has a `.` in it. That is not on your list. Guess you are not into the international market. Umlauts?

Comment: @EdHeal the id is independant from the email. The email can contain whatever characters you want, It's just that the random id I generate only allows specific characters. If you are curious, you can check that out also: https://github.com/Rismosch/risWebsite/blob/main/website/newsletter.php

Comment: I will also look into prepared statements, the link @paulsm4 posted. This is new to me and checking it out wont hurt I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: Why would a user which only deletes rows require the select-privilege?

A: Because you have "where id=xyz" in your delete statement.

From the documentation:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_delete
>
> The SELECT privilege is also needed for other statements that read
> column values

And yes, you should definitely consider using [prepared statements](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-prepared-statement.aspx/)

Comment: Seems to make sense, Somehow it didn't seem obvious to me.